# setContentView() not working as expected - why?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am making an app an tried using setContentView in Android Studio when i used it the layout changed but the app is still using the first java it is not changing the code is given bellow

i tried changing the file up i also tried creating a new empty file but it didnt work
:-

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private int progress = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ProgressBar progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(progress < 100) {
                    progress++;
                    android.os.SystemClock.sleep(25);
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            progressBar.setProgress(progress);
                        }
                    });
                }
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        setContentView(R.layout.activity_on_boarding);

                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

xml:-

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="187dp"
        android:layout_height="141dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.137"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="307dp"
        android:layout_height="210dp"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.52"
        tools:fontFamily="casual"
        />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.795" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

second java:-

```
package com.thebetterside.wallex;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class OnBoarding extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button go = findViewById(R.id.go);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_on_boarding);

        go.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        setContentView(R.layout.activity_name);
                    }
                }
        );


    }

}
```

2nd xml:-

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".OnBoarding">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/go"
        android:layout_width="351dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_peach"
        android:text="@string/go"
        android:textColor="#000046"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.945" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: It sounds like it's working exactly as it's expected to work. You should "read the fine manual" a bit first before declaring something as not working.

Comment: That was because it was working the way i did it few days back i dont know how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do `startActivity(this, OnBoarding.class)` instead of calling the `setContentView()`

`setContentView()` sets the layout for the current activity, it does not start the second one.

And judging from the code you posted, you want to transfer control to your other java file (`OnBoarding.java`) and that must be done by starting that activity explicitly.

EDIT: in your case, it'll most probably be `MainActivity.this.startActivity(MainActivity.this, OnBoarding.class)` because just `this` will point to the thread, instead of the enclosing Context/Activity

Comment: i tried that one out but it shows error so i tried searching for it and found something on the android document it said to make an intent with ur parameter i.e. ```this,OnBoarding.class``` i did that to and now the program crashes every time i use it....
here is what i did
```Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OnBoarding.class);
                        MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);```

Thanks For Helping